# How can I access/read jqXHR fields from my program

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools, jqxhr

I have a code that calls execution of a remote code. Upon successful completion, I need to save the total time it took (the same time value that is shown in chrome developers console). The part of my ajax call is:

```
function callJSON(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://x.php',
    crossDomain: true,
        data: {matrix:input1[array]},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(res, textStatus, jqXHR) 
               {
        console.log(jqXHR.status);          
       },
               error: function (res1, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('POST failed.');
     }
    });//AJAX
    }//CALLjsonone
```

the code works fine and everything is okay. I am able to get the status using           console.log(jqXHR.status) code. But, I am looking for a command to get the time or size fields shown in chrome developer console. It should probably be like            console.log(jqXHR.X.time); that X is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a timer, something like this:

```
time = 0;
window.setInterval(function()
{
    time += 100;        
}, 100);
```

right before your ajax call, then after the call, in your success method;

```
console.log("call took: " + time);
```

and at last:

```
window.clearInterval();
```

Comment: yes, I am currently using that, buy I was intending to avoid using self timer.

Comment: You could use new Date() before run, and in success callback, and calculate difference

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to output time data to the console you should use `console.time('bla'); console.timeEnd('bla');` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoletimelabel)).

[image: console.time devtools example]

Comment: I like this solution though it is again self timer and its value are different from the one Chrome itself produces. Lets see if anyone else comes up with what I exactly need. Tnx for your time dude.